# jw player not playing live stream on android

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

Live videos are playing fine in desktop browser but not in android and IOS devices. I am getting [image]. When I am removing key `androidhls` then player is initialising but giving error "no playable source found".

My Html Code

```
<div id="live-data"></div>
```

Here is my player code.

```
function successLiveCallBack(response){      
 var url = response.eventUrls[1].url || response.eventUrls[0].url;
jwplayer("live-data").setup({
        autostart:true,
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        fallback: true,
        startparam: "fs",//starttime, start, ec_seek, apstart, fs
        androidhls: true,
        file: url,
        primary: "html5",
        type: "mp4",
        deliveryType: "streaming",
        player: {
            modes: {
                linear: {
                    controls: {
                        stream: {
                            manage: false, enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        shows: {
            streamTimer: {
                enabled: false, tickRate: 100
            }
        }
    }).onReady(function(){
        document.querySelector('#screenLoader').style.display= 'none';
        document.querySelector('#live-data-caption').style.display= 'block';
    })

  jwplayer().onError(function(a,b){

  })

}
```

Comment: what does android and ios have to do with this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **free** version of JW player then HLS is not supported, it only supported in **Premium** versions, recently i also spend a lot time till found this article ...

look here - https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-reference

> Apple's HLS protocol, using M3U8 manifest files and TS media files. HLS builds upon standard HTTP, making it easy to deploy and firewall resilient. All JW Player editions support HLS on mobile devices, but only the Premium and higher support HLS on desktop browsers. See Using Apple HLS Streaming for more info.

Comment: Amen: thanks for you reply, The mistake is from my side. I was using defer attribute on jwplayer script that was causing problem. I have removed that and player is working but however it is new error which is "Error loading media: File could not be played"